# Calculate Proration Cost in Stripe using Elixir

Tags: elixir, stripe-payments

I am trying to calculate proration cost in Stripe using Elixir.
I am using Stripity_Stripe library 
https://github.com/code-corps/stripity_stripe/tree/2.0-alpha

Here is what I did.

1. Get a current time as unix time

> ```
> proration_date = DateTime.to_unix(DateTime.utc_now)
> ```

2. Get an upcoming invoice using Stripe.Invoice

> ```
> params = %{customer: customer_id,
>            subscription: subscription_id,
>            subscription_items: [%{plan: plan_id}],
>            subscription_proration_date: proration_date}
>
> upcoming_invoice = Invoice.upcoming(params, opts)
> ```

I substitute customer_id to customer's id and subscription_id to customer's subscription_id and plan_id to new plan_id(that wants to make change) and subscription_proration_date as proration_date

it returns as

```
{:ok,
 %Stripe.Invoice{
   amount_due: 17226,
   application_fee: nil,
   attempt_count: 0,
   attempted: false,
   charge: nil,
   closed: false,
   currency: "usd",
   customer: "cus_CxY2gOrcBX568N",
   date: 1530382817,
   description: nil,
   discount: nil,
   ending_balance: nil,
   forgiven: false,
   id: nil,
   lines: %Stripe.List{
     data: [
       %{
         amount: 5235,
         currency: "usd",
         description: "Remaining time on Gold after 04 Jun 2018",
         discountable: false,
         id: "ii_1CZJOQE0U7CBdOnaJ2JiTU3p",
         invoice_item: "ii_1CZJOQE0U7CBdOnaJ2JiTU3p",
         livemode: false,
         metadata: %{},
         object: "line_item",
         period: %{end: 1530382817, start: 1528121306},
         plan: %Stripe.Plan{
           amount: 6000,
           created: 1527787728,
           currency: "usd",
           id: "plan_CxqGQzrlZKzsyX",
           interval: "month",
           interval_count: 1,
           livemode: false,
           metadata: %{},
           name: "Gold",
           object: "plan",
           statement_descriptor: "Gold",
           trial_period_days: nil
         },
         proration: true,
         quantity: 1,
         subscription: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
         subscription_item: "si_CzHykruREBJmer",
         type: "invoiceitem"
       },
       %{
         amount: -1991,
         currency: "usd",
         description: "Unused time on Bronze after 31 May 2018",
         discountable: false,
         id: "ii_1CXyMGE0U7CBdOna7pMyz65c",
         invoice_item: "ii_1CXyMGE0U7CBdOna7pMyz65c",
         livemode: false,
         metadata: %{},
         object: "line_item",
         period: %{end: 1530382817, start: 1527802256},
         plan: %Stripe.Plan{
           amount: 2000,
           created: 1527789541,
           currency: "usd",
           id: "plan_CxqkbcqfX4hDB8",
           interval: "month",
           interval_count: 1,
           livemode: false,
           metadata: %{},
           name: "Bronze",
           object: "plan",
           statement_descriptor: nil,
           trial_period_days: nil
         },
         proration: true,
         quantity: 1,
         subscription: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
         subscription_item: "si_Cxr5FLLMsPXBhq",
         type: "invoiceitem"
       },
       %{
         amount: 3982,
         currency: "usd",
         description: "Remaining time on Silver after 31 May 2018",
         discountable: false,
         id: "ii_1CXyMGE0U7CBdOnazohKmlP6",
         invoice_item: "ii_1CXyMGE0U7CBdOnazohKmlP6",
         livemode: false,
         metadata: %{},
         object: "line_item",
         period: %{end: 1530382817, start: 1527802256},
         plan: %Stripe.Plan{
           amount: 4000,
           created: 1527787680,
           currency: "usd",
           id: "plan_CxqFiVIY2FqTL3",
           interval: "month",
           interval_count: 1,
           livemode: false,
           metadata: %{},
           name: "Silver",
           object: "plan",
           statement_descriptor: "Silver",
           trial_period_days: nil
         },
         proration: true,
         quantity: 1,
         subscription: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
         subscription_item: "si_Cxr5FLLMsPXBhq",
         type: "invoiceitem"
       },
       %{
         amount: 4000,
         currency: "usd",
         description: nil,
         discountable: true,
         id: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
         livemode: false, 
         metadata: %{},
         object: "line_item",
         period: %{end: 1533061217, start: 1530382817},
         plan: %Stripe.Plan{
           amount: 4000,
           created: 1527787680,
           currency: "usd",
           id: "plan_CxqFiVIY2FqTL3",
           interval: "month",
           interval_count: 1,
           livemode: false,
           metadata: %{},
           name: "Silver",
           object: "plan", 
           statement_descriptor: "Silver",
           trial_period_days: nil
         },
         proration: false,
         quantity: 1,
         subscription: nil,
         subscription_item: "si_Cxr5FLLMsPXBhq",
         type: "subscription"
       },
       %{
         amount: 6000,
         currency: "usd",
         description: nil,
         discountable: true,
         id: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
         livemode: false,
         metadata: %{},
         object: "line_item",
         period: %{end: 1533061217, start: 1530382817},
         plan: %Stripe.Plan{
           amount: 6000,
           created: 1527787728,
           currency: "usd",
           id: "plan_CxqGQzrlZKzsyX",
           interval: "month",
           interval_count: 1,
           livemode: false,
           metadata: %{},
           name: "Gold",
           object: "plan",
           statement_descriptor: "Gold",
           trial_period_days: nil
         },
         proration: false,
         quantity: 1,
         subscription: nil,
         subscription_item: "si_CzHykruREBJmer",
         type: "subscription"
       }
     ],
     has_more: false,
     object: "list",
     total_count: 5,
     url: "/v1/invoices/upcoming/lines?customer=cus_CxY2gOrcBX568N&subscription=sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD&subscription_proration_date=1528121306"
   },
   livemode: false, 
   metadata: %{},
   next_payment_attempt: 1530386417,
   object: "invoice",
   paid: false,
   period_end: 1530382817,
   period_start: 1527790817,
   receipt_number: nil,
   starting_balance: 0,
   statement_descriptor: nil,
   subscription: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
   subscription_proration_date: 1528121306,
   subtotal: 17226,
   tax: nil,
   tax_percent: nil,
   total: 17226,
   webhooks_delivered_at: nil
 }}
```

3. So I did a pattern match to get data items as this(https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/prorations)

> {:ok, %Stripe.Invoice{lines: %Stripe.List{data: data}}} = upcoming_invoice

4. Then I tried this

   data |> Enum.find(& &1.period.start == proration_date)
5. it returns this

> ```
> %{
>   amount: 5235,
>   currency: "usd",
>   description: "Remaining time on Gold after 04 Jun 2018",
>   discountable: false,
>   id: "ii_1CZJPIE0U7CBdOna36eKJQfg",
>   invoice_item: "ii_1CZJPIE0U7CBdOna36eKJQfg",
>   livemode: false,
>   metadata: %{},
>   object: "line_item",
>   period: %{end: 1530382817, start: 1528121306},
>   plan: %Stripe.Plan{
>     amount: 6000,
>     created: 1527787728,
>     currency: "usd",
>     id: "plan_CxqGQzrlZKzsyX",
>     interval: "month",
>     interval_count: 1,
>     livemode: false,
>     metadata: %{},
>     name: "Gold",
>     object: "plan",
>     statement_descriptor: "Gold",
>     trial_period_days: nil
>   },
>   proration: true,
>   quantity: 1,
>   subscription: "sub_Cxr5eVusfDmwpD",
>   subscription_item: "si_CzHzbTUPBrfqPA",
>   type: "invoiceitem"
> }
> ```

Then I don't know what to do next.
In stripe documents using python, do it like this.

```
current_prorations = [ii for ii in invoice.lines.data if ii.period.start == proration_date]
cost = sum([p.amount for p in current_prorations])
```

but my code return only 1 result and I upgraded plan to check if my code return correct cost, but it was not correct.

What am I missing?

Comment: What if you change `Enum.find` to `Enum.filter`? I think you want all the elements which satisfy that criteria?

Comment: Thanks, It will work better, but my question is, how to properly calculate the proration cost.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward translation of your two lines of Python code would be this:

```
current_prorations = for ii <- invoice.lines.data, ii.period.start == proration_date, do: ii
cost = for(p <- current_prorations, do: p.amount) |> Enum.sum()
```